# Why the owner itself can't list the directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions

With 777 permissions on the directory:

```
sudo ls -al  /home/debian/mydoc/source/document
total 144
drwxrwxrwx  2 debian debian  4096 Mar 16 20:21  .
```

Execute `ls` by its owner?

```
debian@mydebian:~$ ls -al  /home/debian/mydoc/source/document
ls: cannot access '/home/debian/mydoc/source/document': Permission denied
```

Why the owner itself can't list the directory?

Comment: Most probably, `debian` doesn't have permissions to access `mydoc` or `source`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what the permissions on all directories above that one (going back to root).

If 1 of them doesn't allow 'x' access your lookup path can't cross those directories...
I.e. if, say 'home' only allows 'rx' by root, or if 'source' has all of its 'x' bits cleared, a regular user won't be able to even get to directory document.  I.e. notice this example:

```
> ll /h/db/mydoc/src/document
ls: cannot access '/h/db/mydoc/src/document': Permission denied
```

That's because I set root as owner of directory /h/db:

```
> sudo ls -ald /h/db /h/db/mydoc /h/db/mydoc/src
drwx------ 3 root lg 27 Apr  2 22:47 /h/db
drwxrwx--- 3 lw   lg 17 Apr  2 22:47 /h/db/mydoc
drwxrwx--- 3 lw   lg 22 Apr  2 22:47 /h/db/mydoc/src
```